# UI Button's EventTrigger doesn't respond to OnPointerDown nor OnPointerUp

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, eventtrigger

I've been trying for a while to make a button that does an action while being pressed and another one when released. I found out that people usually uses EventTriggers to do that kind of things, but the button doesn't respond to being pressed nor released, despite there being an EventSystem in the Hierarchy. Here's the Event Trigger of the Button on the Inspector (It's called MoveUp).:

[image]

And the Inspector of the Canvas. Changing Blocking Mask to Everything doesn't change nothing.

[image]

Also the MainCamera Inspector. Added the Graphics Raycaster because I readed it was needed.

[image]

And the Inspector of the Event System, even if I didn't change anything:

[image]

Here's the Canvas Hierarchy.

[image]

And a snippet of the button script:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? Hope I've revealed enough details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using IPointerDownHandler instead of IPointerClickHandler

Comment: I tried it (also added IPointerUpHandler) but it didn't work...

Comment: Does it have image component or any clickable thing? In inspector, check if it shows Transform or RectTransform. I once made a mistake of putting normal(non-ui) object under Canvas and wondered why UI doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues with your setup.

The Graphics Raycaster should have the Blocking Mask set to Everything (by default).

You can remove the Physics 2D Raycaster. The Graphics Rayctaser is what you use for UI ray casting.

You can remove the IPointerClick handler from your ButtonCode mono behaviour. The Event Trigger component implements all the required interfaces, and calls the methods in your ButtonCode component.

If you follow that, you should be able to interact with you buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem! Inspired by Milan's answer, I tried to check if the button was clickable, but I found that not. So I've did a bit of research and found out that you could look t the bottom part of the EventSystem in the Inspector while playing to find out what where you clicking on the UI. Turned out I'd a Text with it's Rect Transform so big it was over the button! Thanks to both MarkSouls and Milan Egon Votrubec for answering this question!